Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade to 24.04, but now in emergency mode
I have a laptop ASUS-G614JVR. I upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 by clicking the button of App "Software Updater".
Then suddenly the screen blacks, and a cursor "_" on the top. I wait a moment, then have to reboot by pressing the laptop power button.
Now, I am in emergency mode and don't know what to do. I get the "journalctl -xb" log below. Need help, please.
All logs here
Some errors:
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: audit: type=2000 audit(1725106613.020:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'power_allocator'
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: EISA bus registered
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: cpuidle: using governor ladder
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: cpuidle: using governor menu
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: PCI: ECAM [mem 0xc0000000-0xce0fffff] (base 0xc0000000) for domain 0000 [bus 00-e0]
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: PCI: not using ECAM ([mem 0xc0000000-0xce0fffff] not reserved)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: kprobes: kprobe jump-optimization is enabled. All kprobes are optimized if possible.
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: HugeTLB: registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: HugeTLB: 16380 KiB vmemmap can be freed for a 1.00 GiB page
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: HugeTLB: registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: HugeTLB: 28 KiB vmemmap can be freed for a 2.00 MiB page
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.I2C1.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/dswload2-162)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.I2C3.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/dswload2-162)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS11._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS11._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS12._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS12._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS13._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS13._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: 18 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PC00.LPCB.SEN2 (20230628/dspkginit-438)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF988F42938800 000394 (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20200717)
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF988F422BA000 00053F (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20200717)

one error:
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: acpi INT3420:00: hash matches
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: clk: Disabling unused clocks

one error:
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: input: ASUSTek Computer Inc. N-KEY Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:0B05:19B6.0002/input/input15
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: asus 0003:0B05:19B6.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [ASUSTek Computer Inc. N-KEY Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: asus 0003:0B05:19B6.0003: hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [ASUSTek Computer Inc. N-KEY Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: asus 0003:0B05:19B6.0003: Asus input not registered
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: asus: probe of 0003:0B05:19B6.0003 failed with error -12
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: fbcon: Taking over console
8月 31 12:16:56 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x50

the last a few lines:
8月 31 12:18:26 sysescool-G614JVR systemd-resolved[536]: Positive Trust Anchors:
8月 31 12:18:26 sysescool-G614JVR systemd-resolved[536]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
8月 31 12:18:26 sysescool-G614JVR systemd-resolved[536]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172.in-addr.arpa 24.172.in-addr.arpa 25.172.in-addr.arpa 26.172.in-addr.arpa 27.172.in-addr.arpa 28.172.in-addr.arpa 29.172.in-addr.arpa 30.172.in-addr.arpa 31.172.in-addr.arpa 168.192.in-addr.arpa d.f.ip6.arpa corp home internal intranet lan local private test
8月 31 12:18:26 sysescool-G614JVR systemd-resolved[536]: Using system hostname 'sysescool-G614JVR'.
8月 31 12:18:26 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit systemd-resolved.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit systemd-resolved.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 145.
8月 31 12:18:31 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 468 (plymouthd).
8月 31 12:18:31 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 468 (plymouthd).
8月 31 12:18:58 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).


If it's impossible to find a way to boot correctly, you could try to create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive to recover your files (enter the demo version and transfer your files to a cloud or on an external hard drive). As I imagine that you cannot boot the device you wanted to upgrade, you can use another Linux, Window or Apple device following the steps described here. Once your files recovered, you could install Ubuntu 24.04 using the USB drive.

I fix this by use USB Ubuntu live according to the chapter Update Failure in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery.
I use a ubuntu 22.04 live usb to fix it.
then create a ubuntu 24.04.1 usb to update it.
Update Failure

If there was an update that made your system non-bootable and they have fixed it in the repositories, you can use the Live CD to run apt-get to get the new files to fix your system.

    Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.

    Press Ctrl-Alt-F1

    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

    sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

    sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

    sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

    sudo chroot /mnt

    apt update

    apt upgrade 

If you have trouble accessing your network after chroot, you probably use DHCP and can work around this by adding OpenDNS name servers to your /etc/resolv.conf after you use chroot:

nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220

Then I don't know why no GUI. I fix it with apt-get install ubuntu-desktop.
Then I don't know why keyboard and mouse can not be used. I fix it with sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all.
Even in 24.04.1 usb live, mouse and keyboard can not be used to. so I fix it with ubuntu 20.04 usb live.
I am not sure if I fix it right, but now I am using 24.04.1 LTS.
